# Azure ADF: Extract objects in a document to separate rows

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

```
{
        "Events": {  
           "2022-12-30T22:01:00": {
                "GrossVolume": 16888.67,
                "DipHeight": 1562.28,
                "WaterHeight": 0,
                "IsManual": false,
            },
            "2022-12-30T22:05:00": {
                "GrossVolume": 16873.53,
                "DipHeight": 1561.27,
                "WaterHeight": 0,
                "IsManual": false,
            }       
       },
        "id": "20221230",
}
```

I have a delta table save in Azure Data lake. Above is the structure of the documents. How to create a row for each object in "Events" and save to a separate delta table in Data Flow? For example:

```
{
  "id": "20221230",
  "time": "2022-12-30T22:01:00",
  "GrossVolume": 16888.67,
  "DipHeight": 1562.28,
  "WaterHeight": 0,
  "IsManual": false,
}
```

I have tried to convert the objects to an array then use the flatten procedure, but due to the limitation of Data Flow, it's impossible to work with objects with dynamic keys, and thus impossible to convert it to array. Are there other ways to achieve the same key?

Answer (score 0):

- I was able to achieve the requirement using both azure data factory and azure dataflows.
- I have used the dataflow to get the value of id using sink cache and write the keys (timestamp) to a file. The following is the dataflow JSON:

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Json1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                },
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Json1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source2"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "sink2"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "select1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select2"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          Events as ({2022-12-30T22:01:00} as (GrossVolume as double, DipHeight as double, WaterHeight as integer, IsManual as boolean), {2022-12-30T22:05:00} as (GrossVolume as double, DipHeight as double, WaterHeight as integer, IsManual as boolean)),",
                "          id as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     documentForm: 'singleDocument') ~> source1",
                "source(output(",
                "          Events as ({2022-12-30T22:01:00} as (GrossVolume as double, DipHeight as double, WaterHeight as integer, IsManual as boolean), {2022-12-30T22:05:00} as (GrossVolume as double, DipHeight as double, WaterHeight as integer, IsManual as boolean)),",
                "          id as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     documentForm: 'singleDocument') ~> source2",
                "source1 select(mapColumn(",
                "          each(Events,match(true()))",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "source2 select(mapColumn(",
                "          id",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select2",
                "select1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     partitionFileNames:['op.csv'],",
                "     umask: 0022,",
                "     preCommands: [],",
                "     postCommands: [],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     saveOrder: 1,",
                "     partitionBy('hash', 1)) ~> sink1",
                "select2 sink(validateSchema: false,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     store: 'cache',",
                "     format: 'inline',",
                "     output: true,",
                "     saveOrder: 1) ~> sink2"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

- In the pipeline, I have the built the data as required using the file written by the above dataflow. I read it using lookup activity (dataset with first row as header unchecked). I have used iterations and variable activities to get the desired result. The following is the pipeline JSON:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Data flow1",
                "type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataflow": {
                        "referenceName": "dataflow1",
                        "type": "DataFlowReference"
                    },
                    "compute": {
                        "coreCount": 8,
                        "computeType": "General"
                    },
                    "traceLevel": "None"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Data flow1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "loopup_noheader",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "activity": "id",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@range(0,length(split(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0]),',')))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Set variable1",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "tp",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "{\n    \"time\":\"@{activity('Lookup1').output.value[0][concat('Prop_',item())]}\",\n    \"id\":\"@{variables('id')}\"\n}",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable1",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Set variable1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "final",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@union(json(variables('tp')),json(activity('Lookup1').output.value[1][concat('Prop_',item())]))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable2",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "req",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@variables('final')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "id",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Data flow1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "id",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink2.value[0].id",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "tp": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "final": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "req": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "id": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

[image]

- You can write this variable value to a JSON file and then copy to required destination.

Comment: Could this solution scale if we are processing millions of documents at a time?

Comment: The size of the data would be a problem. More number of timestamps results in more number of columns in the file written by the dataflow. Since the memory limitation of the look up activity is 4mb, the size would impact the solution.